# Delete duplicate relationships with the same value of property saving other relationships with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to delete duplicate relationships with the same value of property (year) with Cypher where multiple relationships exist between the nodes. With the example, given:

```
n1-[r{year:"2019"]->n2
n1-[r{year:"2019"]->n2
n1-[r{year:"2020"]->n2
```

I expect:

```
n1-[r{year:"2019"]->n2
n1-[r{year:"2020"]->n2
```

I don't need to combine properties to "2019,2020", want to save multiple relationships with different property (year).

Tried to change these working codes for nodes and relationships for my task:

```
MATCH (n1),(n2)
WHERE n1.name = n2.name and id(n1) < id(n2)
WITH [n1,n2] as ns
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(ns) 
YIELD node
RETURN node


MATCH (n1) -[r]-> (n2) 
WITH n1,n2, collect(r) as rels 
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships(rels) 
YIELD rel 
RETURN rel
```

But I can't normally write part after WITH

```
MATCH (n1) -[r1]-> (n2), (n1) -[r2]-> (n2) 
WHERE r1.year = r2.year and id(r1) < id(r2)
WITH #??? collect(?) as rels   
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships(rels) 
YIELD rel 
RETURN rel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use grouping instead.

```
MATCH (:Foo) -[r:TYPE]->(:Bar)
WITH r.year as year collect(r) as rels
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships(rels) 
YIELD rel 
RETURN rel
```

not sure what you mean with:

> But I can't normally write part after WITH

Comment: thanks that works but with some addition. If there're many and different nodes then there will be an error "All Relationships must have the same start and end nodes". In this case  this code will work:   `MATCH (a) -[r:TYPE]->(b)  WITH r.year as year, [a,b] as ab, collect(r) as rels `